# Java: Restart Java Process on Debian Server

Tags: java, linux, process, debian

I'm using a remote server and to clean up some amount of RAM I've restarted some (not system) services in use but I can't restart the java process because the 'service' command can't find it (isn't a service? it's an oracle-java8 installation through the official apt-get installer).

[image]

Any suggestion?

[I've readed the other questions but there is not a proper solution for my case, I don't want to execute strange scrips. sorry]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I've verified that the java process is the execution of a jar, so just killing and re-launch it.

The clue has been that in my local pc the jre don't have a daemon-like process.

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get install oracle-java8-jdk/jre` would not create java as a service. It would install the JDK/JRE so that you can run jar files as such:

```
# java -jar myjarfile.jar
```

The java process on your server might have been started this way in a console or tty.

If you want to run this jar as a service, you need to create a wrapper script that supports start, stop, restart etc. ([like explained here](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/linux-java-service-wrapper-example)) Without a wrapper script, a java .jar program cannot be managed as a service on Linux.

If your java process was a tomcat server, as read in the comment, you could start it by manually by running

```
# catalina.sh start
```

Tomcat comes with wrapper scripts to run it as a service. If it was installed this way on your server, you could try to start it using

```
# sudo service tomcat8 start
```

See [tomcat running documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/RUNNING.txt) for more info

Comment: Thanks, understood. I will keep this for the future, for now I want only restart the process without restart the remote server.

I trying on my pc if killing the process and launch manually the JRE may works, but not is easy to find the right directory

Comment: Before killing, did you get a full path/more details by running `ps -ef | grep java`?

Comment: I've found the executable in /usr/lib/java-8-oracle/jre/bin but right now I can't replicate the same situation of the server because I don't have tomcat as a service.
I think that killing the java process and start the tomcat service may work but before testing it on server I want to be safe

Comment: If your java proces was a tomcat server, you should know that tomcat comes with various scripts for stopping and starting the server. Look for a script called catalina.sh, that comes with tomcat. You could start tomcat using `catalina.sh start`. See [RUNNING.txt](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/RUNNING.txt) documentation (I.e. for tomcat 8.5). If tomcat was installed using the debian package manager, it will probably be already available as a service indeed.

Comment: Thanks, I've used it in this way once! but I've forgot it.
In the server I've found that the java process was the execution of a jar that I've restarted without problem :)